# Live Website Shipping Method Problem in Magento

Tags: magento-enterprise, checkout, shipping-methods, ups

We are not getting the `UPS Shipping Methods` in `Checkout Section`. When We have change the `Mode` as `Development` it's working correctly, after changing the `Mode` as `Live` it's not working (**UPS Shipping Methods**) and not getting in `Checkout Section`. And earlier it's working fine either Mode as `Development` or `Live`. We have recently changed the **SSL Certificate** for **Magento Website**. From now when I have change the `Mode` as `Development` it's working and getting shipping methods, but `Live` **Mode** it's not working.

[image]

Could you please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by `Development` vs `Live`. The default **Magento UPS** module has no settings for `Live` vs `Development`. So, I'm assuming you're referring to a development environment vs a live environment. Since these are different, you should also check to make sure you have entered a proper shipping origin. UPS relies on that to deliver shipping results.

If you're using the default UPS module, you should turn on the **Debug** feature and see if the `system.log` file records any errors. If you're using a third-party module, then it may indeed have a `Development` vs `Live` configuration. In that case, you have to use different credentials for UPS `Dev` vs `Live`.

Comment: I have enable the `Debug` feature and it's created `shipping_ups.log` file. And the request is the same for **Mode** `Development` and `Live` When **Mode** `Development` the result is came, but `Live` **Mode** it's not came. and I have checked my `system.log` file there is no errors belongs to this.

Comment: please see my updated question.

Comment: Looks like you're using an older version of Magento. Later versions have no User/Password needed to query UPS. Or else you're using a third-party extension. You do have to have different account credentials with UPS for using Live or Development queries. Are you entering different credentials?

Comment: @novusweb My store running in India, so all products weight in KGS, if i try to UPS for international customer i am getting an error like : This measurement system is not valid for the selected country, How can i solve this issue?